# Ejabberd and Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp, ejabberd

I have a Rails application with devise-like authentication and a lot of parts that depend on it. Now I want to add a chat between users using ejabberd (xmpp). I was searching through net and found that it's quite possible, but I can't understand how to make authorization in ejabberd server. For example user logins in a Rails app through login page with one credentials how to implement ejabberd loggining in this action? It will not be good to write like "please, put your user pw and ejabbered pw". Other way is to monkey-patch users registration, so ejabbered will use the same pw as user in the database and I will make authorization in one action, but will it be good? And how long user will be online in this way? Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3804011/113848) might be useful.

Comment: @legoscia seems like it can help. Thank you. At least I've found https://github.com/geoiq/digitalgazette/tree/master/mods/chat/files this solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used rails extauth script like this https://github.com/geoiq/digitalgazette/blob/master/mods/chat/files/ejabberd-auth.rb and ruby_bosh gem for my application.
So now ejabberd is using my app to authenticate users. At login (for example) user's jid and password is using by ruby_bosh to make session and get jid, rid and sid saving them to session to use them later in a strophejs.